# Jquery selection is not working in template elements in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, backbone.js

I have a simple form as a template and an initialize method to change the textarea as required. The problem is that I want to target the textarea in order to use Jquery on it but Backbone won't let me. For example, if I want to do `this.$('textarea').css('height', '1em');` instead returns the following in the console:

```
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: <form>, selector: "textarea"]
context: <form>
length: 0
prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]
selector: "textarea"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

I get a similar result if I try `this.$el.find('textarea').css('height', '1em')`.

This is my code:

#### template

```
<script id="reply-form" type="text/template">
      <fieldset>
        <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
        <input type="button" class="cancel btn btn-small" value="Cancel">
        <input type="button" class="send btn btn-success btn-small" value="Send">
      </fieldset>   
</script>
```

#### views.js

```
App.Views.Form = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'form',
    initialize: function() {
        this.startTextarea();
    },

    startTextarea: function(){
        console.log(this.$('textarea').css('height', '1em'));
    },

    template: _.template( $('#reply-form').html() ),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template() );
        return this;
}
```

What can be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really modify the HTML in this way in the `initialize` function, since the template hasn't been rendered yet -- it's not going to find anything.

I think the way to do this is to place the style stuff in the template, or in a CSS file -- that's really where it belongs.  But if you need to modify the template dynamically when you load the view, you'd have to do it before compiling the template.  See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zm8ME/8/) for an example.

```
startTextarea: function(){
    // get the template HTML
    var tmpl = $('#reply-form').html();

    // modify the template
    tmpl = $(tmpl).find('textarea').css('height', '1em')[0].outerHTML;

    // compile the template and cache to the view
    this.template = _.template(tmpl);
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought. But then what can I do to manipulate objects created via a template? Even if I add this.render() to initialize, I get the same result.

Comment: @RobertSmith if you can't put it in the template directly, why not do it in the `render` function?  If you have to modify the template directly, see my update above.

Comment: Thank you very much... but surprisingly it doesn't apply the css. This is very odd.

Comment: @RobertSmith I wasn't actually updating the template -- see my update.

Comment: Right, now it works :-) Although that replaces the rest of the template. Now what? Create two templates? Should I construct this form out of views?

Comment: @RobertSmith I guess I'm not clear on what the goal is... are you trying to use multiple template variants in the same view?

Comment: No, no, but it seems this approach is not likely to be very manageable  dealing with a long template.

Comment: @RobertSmith so why not just put the `style="height: 1em"` in the template itself?

Comment: In this particular case, I wanted to dynamically change a textarea height when the user click on it.

Comment: @RobertSmith that's probably best done in a click event handler, no?  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/twxyb/1/

Comment: Excellent! I think pretty much what I was wondering about can be done using events, so I'm happy camper :-)

Comment: Actually, after adding behavior to the cancel button, I realized that adding your code in response to an event allows to use this.$('textarea').css('height', '1em')